Realtime database chart didn't appear and it says the that has no data in chart while the connection has succesfully done with firebase
I want real-time data from Firebase represented in the Android Studio in chart form. can anybody help me to achieve that goal. I already asked chatgpt and other tutorials but the code in question is all right according to them. Below is the code that I have written.
the emulator
package com.example.wastenotifier;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BarChart chart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the chart
        chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);

        // Get reference to your Firebase Database
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/test/distance");


        // Listen for data changes
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Check if the dataSnapshot has any value
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Get the data from the snapshot
                    Long distance = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);

                    // Prepare the data for the chart
                    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                    entries.add(new BarEntry(0, distance != null ? distance : 0));

                    // Create the dataset
                    BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Distance");
                    BarData barData = new BarData(dataSet);

                    // Update the chart with the new data
                    chart.setData(barData);
                    chart.invalidate(); // Refresh the chart
                } else {
                    // Handle the case when there is no data available
                    chart.clear();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle errors
            }
        });
    }
}



I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

I expected the chart to display the data retrieved from the Firebase, but the code didn't work like I wanted. The code has no error or problem due to Android Studio. I have tried the connection between the Firebase and Android Studio manually and automatically on the tools and it's successfully done. My Firebase projects have an email authentication Does it affect my problem? I'm still beginner in developing mobile apps pls help me!

How do you know there are no errors? First of all, please, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());. Did you get something printed out in the logcat?
